# cross join equivalent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In an app that's being developed there is a use case whereby dates need to be generated from an array of months and another array of years.  Here is an example of representative data in those arrays:

```
const months= ["1", "4", "7", "9"];
const years = ["2021", "2022", "2027"];
```

The necessary result is the first day of each month + year combination, like so:

```
const dates = [
"1/1/2021", "4/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021",
"1/1/2022", "4/1/2022", "7/1/2022", "9/1/2022",
"1/1/2027", "4/1/2027", "7/1/2027", "9/1/2027"
];
```

The way I would do this in T-SQL is as follows -

```
select *
into #months
from
(
    values
    (1),
    (4),
    (7),
    (9)
) d (month);

select *
into #years
from
(
    values
    (2021),
    (2022),
    (2027)
) d (year);

select [dates] = datefromparts(year, month, 1)
from #months
cross join #years;
```

Output:
[image]

So, is there a cross join equivalent in Javascript?  I'd rather use a concise approach like that rather than nested `.forEach()` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build that result by using `Array#map()` calls together, like so:

```js
const months= ["1", "4", "7", "9"];
const years = ["2021", "2022", "2027"];
const dates = years.flatMap(year => {
  return months.map(month => `${month}/1/${year}`);
});
console.log(dates);
```

`flatMap()` is conceptually the same as `map()` and `flat()` together (but more performant).

```js
const months= ["1", "4", "7", "9"];
const years = ["2021", "2022", "2027"];
const dates = years.map(year => {
  return months.map(month => `${month}/1/${year}`);
}).flat();
console.log(dates);
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between the support tables for `flat` and `flatMap`.   Obviously if you need to support older browsers, you can polyfill either of them or use a `reduce-concat` solution.  But I'm not sure there's any good reason for the `.flat` solution when `.flatMap` is clearer and more performant.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I hoped it would be helpful for understanding `.flatMap`, edited to explain that better.

Answer (score 0):

We can write a fairly simple `crossproduct` function that takes two arrays and a function and combines each pair of their product with the function.

It might look like this:

```js
const crossproduct = (xs = [], ys = [], fn = (x, y) => [x, y]) =>
  xs .flatMap ((x) => ys .map ((y) => fn(x, y)))

const months= ["1", "4", "7", "9"]
const years = ["2021", "2022", "2027"]

const dates = crossproduct (years, months, (y, m) => `${m}/1/${y}`)

console .log (dates)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that `crossproduct` has a default function that just returns an array containing the two values.  This is often useful.